# Is there any use for skill points once you complete Ring Fit Adventure's skill board?

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

I have just completed the skill board (by acquiring all the skills) and I noticed that I can keep earning skill Points (In fact, I even have a skill smoothy). Is there any use for the skill points from this point on?

Answer (score 1):

I play this game with my mom sometimes, and she has finished the game multiple times on different Nintendo accounts. We have not found any use for the coins after we have beat it, but I hope that helped. :)